# Is there a scientific basis for the healing properties of chocolate?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, science

> A loud snap made them all jump. Professor Lupin was breaking an enormous slab of chocolate into pieces.
>   ‘Here,’ he said to Harry, handing him a particularly large piece. ‘Eat it. It’ll help.’
>   *Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 67 - UK Hardcover

Throughout the *Harry Potter* series, chocolate is used as the main treatment for contact with a Dementor, which we know is an analogy for depression.

Is there any scientific basis for JK Rowling using chocolate as a medical and psychological treatment in the *HP* series?

Comment: I think this would be more suitable on skeptics.SE or biology.SE than here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I think it's fine to ask about the science behind the fiction on a science fiction/fantasy forum. :)

Comment: But the answers on the other platforms are potentially much better, both because they demand stricter standards of evidence and because they have a lot of subject experts.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm starting to think you may be right. :)

Comment: I suspect Harry Potter wouldn't constitute a "notable source" on skeptics.se.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: She asked it here, she has her reasons and there's no compelling reason to move it elsewhere instead of leaving it here.

Comment: @TangoOversway If that alone were a cogent argument, then we wouldn’t need the “close as off-topic” function. Experience has shown that moving a question is occasionally helpful, however.

Comment: I never thought a question about chocolate would prove to be so controversial! :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Chocolate has been shown to contain [a number of different stimulants and chemicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_effects_of_chocolate#As_a_stimulant) (see below) that may trigger the release of endogenous [endorphins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorphin) ("**endo**genous mo**rphin**e"). However, the antidepressant effects of chocolate seem to have been exaggerated in popular culture. A review article by Parker et al.<sup>1</sup> notes that the concentrations of certain psychoactive ingredients are too low to have a significant effect. The paper concludes:

> For most people chocolate invokes anticipatory and consummatory pleasure, and is therefore an indulgence. When taken in response to a [dysphoric state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphoria) as an ‘emotional eating’ strategy it may provide some transient ‘comforting’ role but it is more likely to
>   prolong rather than abort the dysphoric mood. It is not, as some would claim, an antidepressant.

So, while chocolate may provide some mild and transient stimulatory effect, it does not appear to be an effective antidepressant.

**However**, the known presence of psychoactive chemicals in chocolate (albeit in small quantities) does provide *some* scientific basis for Rowling's use of it as a medical and psychological treatment. A speculative in-universe explanation could be that chocolate simply has additional magical properties that make its inherent chemicals more effective, or perhaps these chemicals are more effective on the magically inclined even at lower concentrations.

1. [Mood state effects of chocolate](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/entrez?Db=pubmed&Cmd=ShowDetailView&TermToSearch=16546266&ordinalpos=3&itool=EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Pubmed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_RVDocSum). Parker G, Parker I, Brotchie H. *J Affect Disord.* 2006 Jun;92(2-3):149-59.

---

[Chemicals in chocolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_effects_of_chocolate#As_a_stimulant):

> - [Anandamide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anandamide)
> - [Arginine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arginine)
> - [Caffeine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine), present in smaller amounts
> - [Dopamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine)
> - [Methylated xanthines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthine) (theobromine, caffeine & theophylline)
> - [Monoamine oxidase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoamine_oxidase)
> - [Oxalic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalic_acid)
> - [Phenethylamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenethylamine), an endogenous alkaloid sometimes described as a 'love chemical; it is quickly metabolized by monoamine oxidase-B and does not reach the brain in significant amounts
> - [Phenylalanine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenylalanine)
> - [Serotonin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin)
> - Sugar
> - [Theobromine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theobromine), the primary alkaloid in cocoa solids and chocolate and partly responsible for chocolate's mood-elevating effect
> - [Theophylline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophylline)
> - [Tryptophan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tryptophan), an essential amino acid and precursor to serotonin

Comment: Good quality chocolate is a very healthy food. Cheap stuff, with lots of fat, is not, which is one place it gets a bad reputatiom from. However, good strong dark chocolate is rather bitter.